# JavaScript object and property not supported in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JavaScript object with some properties and put the some value into them:

```
var summaryViewObject[transactionId] = new Object();
summaryViewObject[transactionId].paymentTotal = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].numberOfTransactions = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].returnedPayment = false;
```

When we get the property like, `returnedPayment` and other it shows error in IE8 but working fine in other browser like Chrome, IE9 and, Firefox.

Please help me understand JavaScript object and property support.

> Error TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'returnedPayment': object is null or undefined

Comment: [tag:java] tag deleted as the question has nothing to do with Java (that I can see). Please comment if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can create a variable that way. I already get an error because of the `[`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work in any browser. IE8 isn't the problem here.

Comment: In the code you showed us you're not getting the value of any property. Please post the part of the code that actually throws this exception, and tell us about its environment (here for example what `summaryViewObject` and `transactionId` are).

Comment: It's working fine and my project is running very well in every browser except IE8. transactionId is a number.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
var summaryViewObject[transactionId] = new Object();
```

is invalid because `summaryViewObject` is undefined, and you can't create the `[transactionId]` property on it before defining it.

Try this:

```
var summaryViewObject = {};
summaryViewObject[transactionId] = {};
summaryViewObject[transactionId].paymentTotal = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].numberOfTransactions = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].returnedPayment = false;
```

Also, `= new Object()` and `= {};` are essentially the same.

Comment: But this is working fine in all browser except IE8. Please provide any plugin kind of thing which make IE8 for Object and property support.

Comment: I disagree that it works in all browsers. Check the console on this fiddle, I get an error in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ADF6S/

Comment: This should work as Jason P has it, as long as `transactionId` has some value that can be used as an indexer like `var transactionId = 3;` or something similar.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, it would work even if the value of `transactionId` was `foo`. It would look for a property called `foo` on the object `summaryViewObject`. See [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Comment: I have also used var summaryViewObject = {}; it also give same error.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: If it does not exist, you get `Uncaught ReferenceError: transactionId is not defined ` or similar, so as long as it is or can be translated as a string it is usable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var transactionId = 0;
var summaryViewObject = new Array();
summaryViewObject[transactionId] = ({
    paymentTotal: 0,
    numberOfTransactions: 0,
    returnedPayment: true});

//These lines below are here to show you that you can now edit them like so:
summaryViewObject[transactionId].paymentTotal = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].numberOfTransactions = 0;
summaryViewObject[transactionId].returnedPayment = false;

//should alert "false" even though we set it to true in the declaration
alert(summaryViewObject[transactionId].returnedPayment);
```

Comment: You're misusing an Array.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: No he doesn't, `summaryViewObject` is an array with one item at index `0`. Might be better an array literal `[]` though.

Comment: I purposefully made it verbose to show the question asker exactly what steps I was taking.  If you see my comments, the three lines setting the object properties are just there as an example of usage.